# Error making corot/turtlebot_arm

Tags: ros, moveit, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all

I'm trying to make corot's latest turtlebot_arm package from here https://github.com/corot/turtlebot_arm on Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo on a Jetson TK1.

When I catkin_make I get build errors in block_detection_action_server.cpp and interactive_manipulation_action_server.cpp which I've traced back to a dependency issue in shape_tools as per here https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2/issues/64

Doing a find for shape_tools and replacing with geometric_shapes fixes the initial error, but then I get hit with this, which cascades into a bunch of other errors:

```
[100%] Built target moveit_setup_assistant
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot_arm/turtlebot_arm_object_manipulation/src/interactive_manipulation_action_server.cpp: In member function 'void turtlebot_arm_object_manipulation::InteractiveManipulationServer::addObjects()':
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot_arm/turtlebot_arm_object_manipulation/src/interactive_manipulation_action_server.cpp:149:35: error: 'class moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface' has no member named 'getObjects'
         planning_scene_interface_.getObjects(planning_scene_interface_.getKnownObjectNames());
```

I imagine my find/replace wasn't the right technique to fix the dependency - does anyone have an idea of what to do?

Thanks

Will

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232831/error-making-corot/turtlebot_arm/) by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had to remove turtlebot_arm_object_manipulation folder to get the package to build in the end

---

Originally posted by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) with karma: 58 on 2016-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0